# Pointing a sub domain to an ip with a port (apache)

Tags: linux, web-server, reverse-proxy

I've been having an issue for a while and none of the answers for similar posts have been working.

My Issue:

I have a domain running on a linux server (using apache): **example.net**;
I have a second server under the same ip running on the domain with a port: **example.net:8083**

I need to direct subdomain.example.net to example.net:8083, how would I do this?

Currently, in my httpd.conf file, I have these lines:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName subdomain.example.net
        ProxyPreserveHost on
        ProxyPass / http://example.net:8083
</VirtualHost>
```

Sadly, this doesn't work.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would not put this in your httpd.conf, but create a seperate vhost.

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias example.com
  ProxyPass / http://subdomain.example:8083/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://subdomain.example.net:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Try this. Make sure you have a vhost other server which is listening to requests on 8083. With `apachectl configtest` you can test if your config is correct. You also need `sudo a2enmod proxy && sudo a2enmod proxy_http && sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: What do you mean by create a seperate vhost? Do you mean a seperate file or something completely different?  What does "sudo a2enmod proxy && sudo a2enmod proxy_http && sudo service apache2 restart" do? I apologize for not specifying I'm using CentOS, and I feel like it has something to do with installing. Thanks for your help!

Comment: That enables the proxy modules to be able to redirect and restarts apache. Please do some research what a vhost is, it's part of the core of apache. A Virtual Host is an Apache configuration directive